# How to change function context

Tags: scala

I have my case class:

```
case class MyClass(param : String)( body : => Unit) {

  def save(){ ... }
  def mymethod(){ ... }      

  body
  save
}
```

then I want to use it like this:

```
MyClass("param"){ // this function can not see 'mymethod' ---
  ...                                                       |
  mymethod() //                                            <   
  ...
}
```

Is there possible to make function 'body' be able to access 'mymethod'(and all others methods of class MyClass) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generically no. The usual approach to building a DSL is to use some kind of "command" objects, perhaps with the [Free Monad](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Free+Monad.html):

```
object MyClass {
  sealed trait Command
  case class CallMyMethod() extends Command
  def myMethod() = liftF[Command, Unit](CallMyMethod())
}
case class MyClass(param: String)(body: Free[Command, Unit]) {
  ...
  body.resume.fold({
    case CallMyMethod() => mymethod()
  }, _ => {})
  ...
}
```

Then you can write your DSL "programs" using `for`/`yield` syntax:

```
import MyClass._
MyClass("param")({
  for {
    _ <- myMethod()
    a = someNonMyClassCall()
    b <- someOtherMyClassMethod(a)
  } yield {}
})
```

Note that outside classes can create the `CallMyMethod` objects (since they're on the companion object), but that's fine, they "don't mean anything" until they're "interpreted" by the `MyClass` instance.

Answer (score 2):

Why did you want this?

I see two possibilities:

Give your 'body' function a context argument:

```
case class MyClass(param : String)( body: MyClass => Unit) {
  def mymethod() = println("MyClass.mymethod()")
  body(this)
}

MyClass("test"){ ctx =>
  ctx.mymethod()
}
```

or

Put your utility functions in MyClass companion object:

```
object MyClass {
  def mymethod() = println("MyClass.mymethod()")
}
case class MyClass(param : String)( body:  => Unit) {
  body
}

MyClass("test"){
  import MyClass._
  mymethod()
}
```